# Какая библиотека в СИ шарп отвечает за формат U32

Tags: c#

Мне нужны типы данных, как в си при подключении заголовочного `#include <cstdint.h>` (либо как в си++ `#include <cstdint>` )

***Но увы не знаю как вызвать аналоги таких переменных в  СИ шарп***

```
namespace std {
    int8_t
    int16_t
    int32_t
    int64_t
    int_fast8_t
    int_fast16_t
    int_fast32_t
    int_fast64_t
    int_least8_t
    int_least16_t
    int_least32_t
    int_least64_t
    intmax_t
    intptr_t
    uint8_t
    uint16_t
    uint32_t
    uint64_t
    uint_fast8_t
    uint_fast16_t
    uint_fast32_t
    uint_fast64_t
    uint_least8_t
    uint_least16_t
    uint_least32_t
    uint_least64_t
    uintmax_t
    uintptr_t
}
```

Я уверен такие аналоги в  СИ шарп есть, как их подключить ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По сравнению с С / С++ в C# сделано наоборот: все встроенные целочисленные типы являются алиасами для системных целочисленных типов фиксированной длины. Системные типы определены в пространстве имен `System` и всегда доступны без подключения дополнительных бибилиотек. Например тогда как в С `int32_t` обычно является алиасом для `int` в С# `int` является алиасом для `System.Int32`, аналогом `intptr_t` будет `System.IntPtr`, и т.п. Для всяких `*fast` `*least` прямых аналогов нет, но они и не нужны - ведь размеры встроеных типов гарантируются. Полную таблицу алиасов можно найти в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types). Также стоит отметить, что C# не позволяет создавать пользовательские алиасы типов подобно `typedef` / `using` в C / С++, все алиасы для встроенных типов являются предопределенным ключевыми словами.

Answer (score 0):

```
int8_t -> sbyte
int16_t -> short
int32_t -> int
int64_t -> long
int_fast8_t -> sbyte
int_fast16_t -> short
int_fast32_t -> int
int_fast64_t -> long
int_least8_t -> sbyte
int_least16_t -> short
int_least32_t -> int
int_least64_t -> long
intmax_t -> не уверен, что в шарпе есть аналог
intintptr_t -> IntPtr
uint8_t -> byte
uint16_t -> ushort
uint32_t -> uint
uint64_t -> ulong
uint_fast8_t -> byte
uint_fast16_t -> ushort
uint_fast32_t -> uint
uint_fast64_t -> ulong
uint_least8_t -> byte
uint_least16_t -> ushort
uint_least32_t -> uint
uint_least64_t -> ulong
uintmax_t -> не уверен, что в шарпе есть аналог
uintintptr_t -> UIntPtr
```